# Need help for a SAS problem to get a new variable created basis on the conditional data

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a data as follows - [Credit card transaction data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aCL5.jpg)

I need to add a counter variable for each credit card -- for each date and transaction country type. which should be look like this -[Expected result with New counter variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wy4m2.jpg)

I am trying this with the help of by group (first. last.) but not getting expected result. Help needed for this problem statement. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with applying the concepts `first.` and `last.`. Let me know if this works.

```
proc sort data=work.trans_data;
    by cc_no dot country ts;
run;

data work.trans_data_cnt;
    set work.trans_data;
    by cc_no dot country ts;

    /*This will assign the first row of the cc_no, dot, country = 1*/
    if first.cc_no = 1 and first.dot = 1 and first.country = 1 then
        counter = 1;
    /*Restart counter, we have switched country, but are in the same cc_no and dot.*/
    else if first.country = 1 then
        counter = 1;
    /*Increment the counter, we are within the same cc_no, dot, country.*/
    else
        counter + 1;
run;
```